# How do I make a 3D plot using evenly spaced values?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

This is my assignment question:

> Create a 3D plot of `y = sin(2πx), y = cos(2πx)` over `[0,π]`, using 500 evenly spaced values.

I didn't understand the question because it says to create a 3D plot of `y = sin(2*pi*x)` and `y = cos(2*pi*x)` but both of these functions are 2D plots, not 3D. So I asked for hints. These are the hints I got:

> For the second function use `z = cos(2 pi x)`, instead of `y = cos(2 pi x)`.

This still didn't make sense. Shouldn't `z` should be a function of both `x` and `y` if we are to make a 3D plot, otherwise it can only be made into a 2D plot?

She replied with:

> You have to create a 3d plot using `X` values, that you need to create using linspace command and then calculate the `Y` values (`sin`) and `Z` values (`cos`)..plot `x`, `y` and `z`..

This is what I tried:

```
x = linespace(0, 500);
y = sin(2*pi*x);
z = cos(2*pi*x);
figure;
plot3(x, y, z);
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it though. Did I answer the question correctly?

Comment: What you did looks correct.

Comment: Correction: `x` has only 100 values (not 500). To fix this, you need to use `x=linspace(0, 4, 500);`

Comment: @Aziz Why does it only have 100 values?

Comment: `linspace` takes 3 parameters: start, end, and number of points. If you don't specify the number of points, the default 100 is used. In your code, you used `linspace(0,500)` (start at 0, end at 500).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion is more about the different ways to represent what you want to plot. What you probably have in mind is a function with two parameters which looks like f(x, y)=x+y, typically defining something like a surface. What you received is a [parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation). This code does the same, is just rewritten to match the notation Wikipedia uses:

```
%parametric representation of a spiral
t = linspace(0, pi, 500); %correct use of linspace, see Felix's answer.
x = t;
y = sin(2*pi*t);
z = cos(2*pi*t);
```

Maybe let me rephrase how I would have asked the question:

> Create a 3D plot of the parametric equation x=t, y=sin(2*pi*t), z=cos(2*pi*t) for 500 evenly spaced values of t.

You also ignore the range [0, pi] when calling `linspace`, and the function is called `linspace`, not `linespace`

Comment: Thanks. Is the function name `linspace` or `linespace`? I tried `linespace` and I got an error.

Comment: Yes copied it from your question without noticing, It is `linspace`. Also forgot to set the correct range 0,pi which felix noticed. Now is fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You only want to plot over [0,pi] not over 0 to 500.

```
x = linespace(0, 500);
```

You created a vector of 100 values (this is the default number of the function linspace) between 0 and 500. What you want to do is:

```
x = linspace(0, pi, 500);
```

That will devide the interval 0 to pi in 500 values.

The rest of the code was OK.